# Filter dynamically added file upload fields for specific file types

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding file upload fields using JavaScript.

I need to filter the files so that only PDF files can be uploaded.

Here is what I have so far :

```
function AddFileUpload() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter +
    '" type="file" />' +
    '<input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
    'value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload(this)" />';
    document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
    counter++;
}

function RemoveFileUpload(div) {
    document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}
```

Comment: Hello ! I edited your question so that it's a little more readable, please make sure the question still reflects what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**: Doing this check with Javascript is very, VERY bad. It can be manipulated very easily, and it is definitely not recommended. At all. By anyone. Don't do it.

```
function AddFileUpload() {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter +
        '" type="file" accept="application/pdf"/>' +
        '<input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
        'value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload(this)" />';
    document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
    counter++;
}

function RemoveFileUpload(div) {
    document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}
```

To accept a certain type of file, look into MIME file types and the accept attribute. Example site: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

Comment: It's working for me. Why isn't it working for you? Create a JSFiddle with your code, and I will make sure it works.

Comment: i am not getting wht is JSFiddle ,u r telling abt toll tht is used to build js

Comment: http://jsfiddle.com/ - Searching is allowed, you know. Insert all your code there and make a demo that works. Then save and paste the link here in a comment.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nwuo9zrx/1/ works fine? You just had to add the counter and define the functions correctly. Check your console next time...

Comment: but it is expecting all files,how to restrict other file other then pdf

Comment: It doesn't accept all files. It accepts a PDF file, as you can see here: http://puu.sh/i9pb7.png - If you're on Windows and you can select "All Files", there is no way to bypass that. Which is why you shouldn't be doing this check in HTML. You should do this check on the server. There is no way (client side) to prevent someone from uploading a different file.

Comment: I want to pop up a alert msg to user on button clk cnu jst hlp me out

Comment: I won't help you unless you start improving your English. I can barely read what you're saying. Search for your question on Google or StackOverflow, and you can find your answer almost instantly.

Comment: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Use Google or StackOverflow to search.